# PHP return a mp4 video file

Tags: php, video, mp4

I have the following php script

```
$file_name = 'Videos/'.$_GET['fileName'].'.mp4';

$file_size = (string)(filesize($file_name));
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$file_size);



header("Content-Disposition: inline;");
header("Content-Range: bytes .$file_size");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header('Connection: close');

readfile($file_name);
```

Interestingly it only works well serving some video files but not others recorded with a different bit-rate. Furthermore, if the video-files are access directly then chrome browser display the video without a problem. 
Am I missing some header?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why is not working with all videos, why only works with some.

Comment: Because some bitrates might not be compatible with supported mp4 bitrates  in browsers. Check out https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/encoding-settings/html5

Answer (score 0):

Actually I finally found out that the problem was the appache server.
I just had to increase the memory in php.ini
It is not a problem with bitrates but with the size of the files.

memory_limit=1280M